# Call an AngularJS function on button click is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a requirement where I want to call an AngularJS function on button click. So I tried like below

```js
var app2 = angular.module('grdContrl', ['datatables']);
app2.controller('dtAssignVendor', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
    function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

        $scope.GetFiler = function () {
            var strZone = $('#SAPExecutive_R4GState').val();
            var strUtility = $('#ddlUtility').val();

            $scope.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, '').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="' + full.objectid + '">'
                }),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONENAME", "MAINTENANCEZONENAME"),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONECODE", "MAINTENANCEZONECODE")
            ]
            $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
                url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "/App/GetMPFilter",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ strZone: strZone, strUtility: strUtility }),
            })
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10);
        }        
}])
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="GetFilter();">
    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  Filter
</button>


---------------------------

<div ng-app="grdContrl">
    <div class="flTable" id="dtAssignVendor">
        <table id="assignVender" class="mp myTable table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">                            
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this to work on the above mentioned button click.

Comment: probably because your function in controller is called `GetFiler`, though in template you are referencing `GetFilter`

Comment: @LuninRoman: ohhh, my mistake. let me try and check

Comment: @LuninRoman: nothing happened, I tried adding an alert but that too is not firing

Comment: @BN, Please make sure that you bind the controller.

Comment: @Sultan: yes I have binded it. https://jsfiddle.net/e3gu2hca/. for more info have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/e3gu2hca/1/

Comment: I am getting this error `angular.js:15536 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'dtAssignVendor' is not registered.`

Comment: @BN, The controller you have registered is not in the div structure where you are calling the function, so please register it correctly where in the click function is being registered. Moreover for your register issue here is other stack-over flow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084926/the-controller-with-the-name-maincontroller-is-not-registered

Answer (score 1):

You can not get filter values, because filter button is outside of controller and if you are using `datatable` then also add `dt-option`, `dt-columns` and `dt-instance` into `<table>` as attributes.

You have do like this way

```
<div ng-app="grdContrl" ng-controller="dtAssignVendor"> <!-- COMMON ANCESTOR-->
  <button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="GetFilter();">
    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filter
  </button>
  <div class="flTable" id="dtAssignVendor">
     <table id="assignVender" class="mp myTable table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"  dt-instance="dtInstanceNonInvProduct">                            
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also inject into controller.

```
app2.controller('dtAssignVendor',function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,DTInstances) {
       $scope.GetFiler = function () {
     //get input values into scope instead of javascript variable
    //var strZone = $('#SAPExecutive_R4GState').val();
    //var strUtility = $('#ddlUtility').val();
    $scope.strZone = $scope.SAPExecutive_R4GState;
    $scope.strUtility = $scope.ddlUtility;
    //redraw table on button click
    $scope.dtInstanceNonInvProduct.DataTable.draw();

}  
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
    url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "/App/GetMPFilter",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ strZone: $scope.strZone, strUtility: $scope.strUtility }),
})
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
.withDisplayLength(10);
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, '').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="' + full.objectid + '">'
    }),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONENAME", "MAINTENANCEZONENAME"),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONECODE", "MAINTENANCEZONECODE")
]

$scope.dtInstanceNonInvProduct = {};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see you did not bind the controller to your template, you need to use the `ng-controller` directive and wrap the button inside it (and correct the spelling error on `$scope.getFilter` as raised in the comments)

```
<div ng-app="grdContrl" ng-controller="dtAssignVendor"> <!-- COMMON ANCESTOR-->
  <button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="GetFilter();">
    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filter
  </button>


 ---------------------------
  <div class="flTable" id="dtAssignVendor">
     <table id="assignVender" class="mp myTable table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">                            
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my button is in another div, so will it work as per your answer ?

Comment: need to stay in a common ancestor that has the ng-controller directive to be able to access the method

Comment: cant do the way u mentioned as my button is outside that div. have a look at my whole html part. https://jsfiddle.net/e3gu2hca/

Comment: I am getting this error `angular.js:15536 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'dtAssignVendor' is not registered.`

Comment: i checked your code and you have multiple ng-app directives in your template, you need to refactor your code and put the table and the button inside a common ancestor with the ng-app="grdContrl" and ng-controller="dtAssignVendor"

Comment: can u please help me out.. I am new to angular js.

Comment: are u their, let me know if u can help me

Comment: i cannot help more  than this now, you need to refactor your code taking this as an example :)

Answer (score 0):

The template of your code should be something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div controller="ctrl1">
        <button ng-click="someFunInCtrl1()">Click Me</button>
        ...
    </div>
    <div controller="ctrl2">
        <button ng-click="someFunInCtrl2()">Click Me</button>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You are unable to call `GetFilter` function because you are calling it from outside controller scope. As @Karim said

> you need to use the ng-controller directive and wrap the button inside it